# Twitter and Instagram Web services working within the Intel XDK emulator but not responding on my android and windows phone

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, twitter, instagram

I have an Intel XDK App, with a bootStrap UI Framework.

I called some web services within the app (Twitter and IG) using the "Explore Services" tab within the Intel XDK and I enabled the Cordova Plugins within the XDK.

I then called the web services and entered the necessary Tokens for authentication to get feeds from Twitter and Instagram.

The App works works properly with the Intel XDK Emulator and gets all the feeds but when I built it for My Android and Windows Phone, the page is blank and empty. It shows only my header, and not the feeds from twitter and Instagram.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Hey @Wilmot Bakare, can you add sample code? It's hard to debug otherwise. Thanks! :)

Comment: @yochannah thank you for the response. I used the APP designer so most codes were generated by the XDK. If you are familiar with the process, which of the code samples would you like me to share with you, The HTML or the JS? Thank you